# How convert a string for MS-DOS to display European characters like "éàè"?

Tags: c#, char

I have some problems in writing a MS-DOS batch file with European characters "é"

```
string linedsgrab = @foldername + @"\wget.exe -r --no-host-directories -nH --cut-dirs=5 -P ABC/BASE1/ ftp://" + ipv4 + ligneftpdelabase;

File.AppendAllText(@"wg.bat", linedsgrab, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
var process = Process.Start("wg.bat");
```

This line gives me in the MS-DOS batch "C:\Users\josÚ\Documents\" instead of "josé\documents".

I've read some help and tried ISO-8859-1, utf8, utf16 and utf32, but nothing helps.

Can someone help me to fix this?

Comment: What is `@foldername`? Where do you get that from?

Comment: Works for me if `foldername` value is really  `josé\documents`

Comment: What if you *don't* do anything? The default encoding *is* the system's encoding. BTW there is no MS-DOS and you only *write to a file*. This isn't even related to the Console

Comment: What happens if you just `File.AppendAllText(@"wg.bat", linedsgrab);` ? Do you get any errors when you run the code?

Comment: PS - don't use `.bat`. Batch files have a `.cmd` extension. `.bat` is a leftover from the 90s

Comment: Getting a Ú for 0xE9 will happen when whatever program you are using to look at the .bat file is using code page 850.  Pretty similar to 437, the original IBM PC character set and commonly used in Western Europe and the Americas but with more accented characters.  Ought to be popular in France I imagine.  So you need to use Encoding.GetEncoding(850) to get 0x82, the character code for é in 850.

Comment: foldername is : private string foldername = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

Comment: i've tried without nothing indeed and no problem, but with a machine without this char"é" i just noticed the error in other machine with this kind of path. 
"Users\jos├®\Docume"   without encoding.

Comment: Encoding.GetEncoding(850) works thanks.

Comment: now dos don't understand the spaces in the path name. but i'll find a way.

Comment: "PS - don't use .bat. Batch files have a .cmd extension. .bat is a leftover from the 90s – Panagiotis Kanavos 9 hours ago"@panagiotis

that's what i used in the 80s :)